# How to Switch docker containers programmatically

Tags: docker

I would like to switch from linux containers to windows containers or viceversa, by using the command line. I found the following command: "dockerCLI -SwitchWindowsEngine", for example to switch to windows containers. The problem is that I upgraded to the last docker desktop and the dockerCLI.exe it appears not to be there anymore. Was it substituted by something else or is there another exe to be used for this command? Thank  you